# Combine/Concatenate 2 properties/fields (First Name + Last Name) within a single object using Java Streams

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, java-stream, concatenation

```
    List<CustomerDetails> customerDetailsList = repo.getCustomerDetails();

    Set<String> combinedNamesList = new HashSet<>();

    customerDetailsList.forEach(i -> {
        combinedNamesList .add((i.getFirstName() != null ? i.getFirstName().toLowerCase(): "") + (i.getLastName() != null ? i.getLastName().toLowerCase(): ""));
    });
```

I would like to create the combinedNamesList in one operation using streams. Each CustomerDetails object has properties for a firstName and LastName. I would like to combine the two properties into a single String in an array such as:

```
{BobSmith, RachelSnow, DavidJohnson}
```

Answer (score 3):

Stream the list and filter all customer objetcs having valid firstname and lastname, and then combine the name using `String.format`

```
List<String> combinedNamesList = repo.getCustomerDetails()
           .stream()
           .filter(cust->cust.getFirstName()!=null && cust.getLastName()!=null)
           .map(cust->String.format("%s%s",cust.getFirstName(),cust.getLastName()))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: this worked like a charm mate. thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Deadpool's answer, thinking this might help someone too.

```
    Person p = new Person("Mohamed", "Anees");
    Person p1 = new Person("Hello", "World");
    Person p2 = new Person("Hello", "France");
    System.out.println(
        Stream.of(p, p1, p2)
            .map(person -> String.join(" ", person.getFirstName(), person.getLastName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Here `String.join()` is used to concatenate names. And, this also produces a more sensible output than the one you are expecting

```
[Mohamed Anees, Hello World, Hello France]
```

If you really need names without space, you can replace `" "` in String.join() delimiter to `""`

You can add filter() in the Stream for null checks before converting to lowercase.